# How to hide UINavigationBar when push to another ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alert, navigationbar

I have a ViewController, "ViewController A" and I would like to push to another ViewController, "ViewController B". When I push to ViewController B, I will check the user validation and present a popup alert if the user is not a valid user.

How can I hide the UINavigationBar as my current code is not working properly. Please help. Thanks!

**ViewController A**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(indexPath.row==0) //Wishlist
    {
            WishList_ViewController *WishList_ViewControl = [[WishList_ViewController alloc]init];
           // [self cw_presentViewController:WishList_ViewControl];
         [self cw_pushViewController:WishList_ViewControl];
    }
}
```

**ViewController B**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"My Wishlist";

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLogin"])
    {
        //THIS CODE DOES NOT WORKING
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

        //Check whether is login or not
        SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];
        [alert addButton:@"Done" target:self selector:@selector(btnLoginClick:)];
        alert.customViewColor = ThemeBlueColor;
        [alert showWaiting:self title:@"Login" subTitle:@"Please login to view your wishlist"
          closeButtonTitle:nil duration:2.0f ];

        [alert alertIsDismissed:^{
            [self btnLoginClick:nil];
        }];
    }
}
```

**Current result:**
[image]

Comment: Please post cw_pushViewController method code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"My Wishlist";

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isLogin"])
    {

        self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;

        //Check whether is login or not
        SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];
        [alert addButton:@"Done" target:self selector:@selector(btnLoginClick:)];
        alert.customViewColor = ThemeBlueColor;
        [alert showWaiting:self title:@"Login" subTitle:@"Please login to view your wishlist"
          closeButtonTitle:nil duration:2.0f ];

        [alert alertIsDismissed:^{
            [self btnLoginClick:nil];
        }];
    }
}
```